# GraphLab Create Launcher installation error

Tags: python, windows, git, anaconda, graphlab

Why problem creating the "gl-env" ?
I have tried reinstalling it also... but nothing help me out.

```
CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: <not set>
CONDA_ENVS_PATH: <not set>
PATH: C:\Users\Himanshu\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Users\Himanshu\Anaconda2;C:\Users\Himanshu\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Users\Himanshu\Anaconda2;C:\Users\Himanshu\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\Himanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Himanshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Users\Himanshu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
PYTHONHOME: <not set>
PYTHONPATH: <not set>

WARNING: could not import _license.show_info
# try:
# $ conda install -n root _license

===================
There was a problem creating the "gl-env" conda environment.  Restart GraphLab Create Launcher.

Process completed with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem. Read elsewhere it is because the PATH variable is too long. I deleted everything possible from the PATH variable and that is not the solution.